# Bootstrap 3 sub theme - missing header for banner?

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I am new with Drupal Bootstrap 3 sub theming, and I checked the view source and noticed:

```
<div class="main-container container">

  <header role="banner" id="page-header">

      </header> <!-- /#page-header -->
```

I wanted to move header outside main-container - how or where can I edit that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the Bootstrap 3 subtheme and in that case you have to modify the corresponding templates. So to do that create a new directory "templates" in your subtheme directory and then there you have to place a `page.tpl.php` then edit as per your needs.

For further reference you can follow, [Theming Guide](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme) & [Bootstrap sub-theming "how to"](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010)

Comment: thanks and I already got it working. But only the issue is to link the banner to image - image path was not correct if I wanted to use one folder: sites/default/images?

Comment: Is it sites/default/images or sites/default/files/images?
If it's sites/default/files then it's in "public://" scheme.